MicroPython: How to wake Pi Pico / Pico W / Pico 2 from sleep using GPIO button?
A lot of people use sleep modes for finite amount of times, waking up after X seconds.
I would like to indefinitely make the microcontroller go to sleep until any of 4 GPIO buttons is pressed.
I can't seem to find a rudimentary example of this. I found some stuff related to other microcontroller boards (ESP32), but the code did not work for the Pico.
Do I use Pin.irq? What arguments should I be using?
Is the code different depending on the sleep state? Light vs deep? What are the differences?

Good luck. Rpi published a couple of sleep examples in their so-called "pico-playground" repo about 3-4 years ago. They've not been updated, and they don't work at all. I've filed issues on their GitHub site, but got only dodgy and/or "word salad" replies. The RPi staff may be out of their depth - or their hardware may just not be up to it. In the meantime, I've moved on to the TI MSP430 & having some good results with that.

Ah I see. Well I'm open to a hardware solution, as I'm learning about electronic components and all. Is there a way to use only hardware to turn the Pi off after a period of inactivity?

There are definitely hardware solutions available. But just so I'm clear, are you talking about turning a Raspberry Pi (as in models 1-5) OFF & ON - or are you asking about turning a Pico OFF & ON?

The Pico microcontrollers. Specifically, I want to wake from sleep though. Not a full power cycle. I believe the knowledge of how to do this is invaluable for making projects that run off of batteries.

"... how to do this is invaluable for making projects that run off of batteries."  It certainly is!  But as I indicated, I've tried and given up on the solution offered by Raspberry Pi, so I can't be of much help. HOWEVER: before you give up, I'd suggest that you try their solution yourself. That will entail your installing the Pico SDK on your computer, and trying the hello_dormant (or hello_sleep) example. You can find these examples in the pico-playground repo. You can start here.

I don't know how much experience you have with this sort of thing, but the documentation is not too bad. You'll likely need to use the C/C++ SDK; I don't think there are any examples of sleep in Python. Give it a go - if you hit any snags, you can ask questions here & we'll do our best to help. You may also find support in the RPi forums - or by reporting an "issue" in their Pico SDK GitHub site - or in one of their other repos.

It should work fine. I have code that sends an MQTT message every 6 hours. If an alarm goes off it wakes up and sends that alarm. Here is my code watchible It does just what you wants. I have also tested the sleep mode and it draws very little current.

It would be good if you provided a quick example of lightsleep and setting an interrupt which can cause it to wake.

I found that it works with micropython v1.23. The newer versions don't work. v1.24 don't work
